# Does azure site recovery replicate app service as its in VM?

Tags: azure

I'm planning to use Azure site recovery Azure-to-Azure architecture as my BCDR strategy.

According to the Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-azure-to-azure-architecture), (if i'm not mistaken) it'll replicate the whole infrastructure.
I've my web application in App service and this app service is deployed in a Virtual Machine maintained by Azure.

My Question is:

> Does this mean site recovery replicates my web application
>   stored in App Service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Site Recovery cannot protect WebApps. You can use other means to protect your WebApps (like traffic manager).

Answer (score 0):

BCDR planning is to achieve High Availability for your business application, services, data. For example, your application is hosted in a data center that resides in a natural disaster zone like an Earthquake, Flood, Tsunami, etc. When these such a bad event will occur there quite a high chance to lose data/application forever even the whole data center that can not be recovered at all if the organization does not have the right BCDR planning.

you can find more here in details: [BCDR With Example Diagram](https://sps-cloud-architect.blogspot.com/2020/01/what-is-business-continuity-and.html)